# Cross-compiling a C program from scratch

Tags: c, compilation, arm, cross-compiling

I own a locked-down modem running the Qualcomm LE operating system based on the linux kernel. Although I am able to SSH into it as a user, I do not have elevated permissions to access many folders. I want to compile a program to run on this device, so I installed Ubuntu on my own x86-64 based computer, but I do not know how to proceed to install the correct gcc toolchain and compile for the triplet `arm-oe-linux-gnueabi`. What steps can I follow to create a binary that works on this device without compiling it natively?
I've included relevant device information below:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MDM9207
Revision        : 0000
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
```

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.18.44 (buildfarm@bf-rmsz-04) (gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) ) #1 PREEMPT Wed May 15 22:09:02 CST 2019
/ $ uname -a
Linux mdm9607 3.18.44 #1 PREEMPT Wed May 15 22:09:02 CST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Executable retrieved form modem:

```
$ readelf -h nativeApp
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x12b0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          16812 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         10
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         32
  Section header string table index: 31
```

Executable I compiled:

```
$ readelf -h compiledByMe
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x10961
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          19180 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000400, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         37
  Section header string table index: 36
```

Comment: Hi @LukeAsch - did you read up on it? e.g. [From GCC.GNU.ORG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc/Configure-Cross.html#Configure%20Cross)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mr R. I did try the target flag, but I got errors when trying to use it after installing gcc (sudo apt install gcc I believe?) I think the error referenced that the function call pthread_create was not available for the platform or something similar. After doing some research I read something about how you need to have a whole toolchain rather than simply a target flag. I don't know if that is true but it seems plausible!

Comment: @LukeAsch For the pthreadnerror I hope you passed in `-pthread` to the compiler?

Comment: @Zoso Yes, I passed that in. I'm going to try to reproduce the error and I will update my post with it, sorry for the lack of information

Comment: Hi @LukeAsch - correct you do need a whole tool chain [well you did last time I did any cross compilation 20+ years ago :-)] - specifically AS, LD (linker), AR/RANLIB (as appropriate for the platform).  Although if you have any of those tools - can generate assembly files and then compile and link on different platform.

Comment: Thanks @Mr R, that's all quite over my head right now! I know as a beginner to learning C (mainly I'm just using code from other people right now as I'm trying to test kernel security) I can see why my original question may sound a little hand-holding. Impressive that you've been working on that topic so long ago, I can imagine it wasn't any easier back then from now!

Comment: @Zoso it seems like whatever I was trying to do originally never actually passed into the compiler's parameters, specifically I'm not able to use --target=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi. Perhaps this is related to Mr R's comment regarding setting up a toolchain? It seems that there are specific precompiled gcc compilers for different architectures, but I was not able to find any for arm-oe-linux-gnueabi.

Comment: @LukeAsch Does the platform you are working on officially support development (like Arduino etc. do) or is this something you are just reverse engineering. Also locked on systems don't imply no gcc, it's just that you might need to install gcc to an alternate location other than `/usr/bin`(which needs `sudo`). You can build gcc on the system from source and should probably be easier to start

Comment: @Zoso It's not an official development platform, I'm reverse engineering it. It's a 4g modem/router combo I bought off ebay, and most of the filesystem is locked down except a few folders. I was only able to ssh into it because of a command that the web interface supported, but I'm stuck as a user with few privileges. I considered installing gcc however the system only has 70mb of free space, which I do not believe is enough.

Comment: @Luke Asch: I would suggest to determine what is the ARM core your device is using, then to use an ARM or Linaro toolchain. 
Is the `/proc/cpuìnfo` entry present in the `/proc` file system? if yes, what is the output for the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo`? Any way you could find the exact Arm core your device is using   on the Internet the from the device model?

Comment: @Frant Yes, it does have that entry. The output it gives me is this: https://imgur.com/a/eiuor3N . Would it still be necessary for me to look online for the exact arm core or does that output include it?

Comment: @Luke Asch: No. Because of the part value being `0xCA7`, your CPU is a Cortex-A7 - see section `4.3.1 Main ID Register` of the [Cortex-A7 MPCore Technical Reference Manual](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f042da1dbdee951c1cd8c11?token=). Could you please copy/paste the output for `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and augment your question with it ? Using images  is not recommended, since it makes difficult for people to easily exploit the information. I will add other comments when this will be done - thanks.

Comment: @Frant thank you for the reference manual link, I wasn't aware such a document existed for the CPU. I have appended the output in text form to my original question.

Comment: @Luke Asch: Because your SoC has the `vfpv4` feature, you probably use a [arm-none-linux-gnueabihf](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads)  toolchain. You will have to use the following options I think when compiling: `-mtune=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4  -mfloat-abi=hard`. Now, you should check what is the version of libc being used in your system. This can be done by transfering an executable from the modem into your Linux system using `scp`, and execute  `readelf -d` on the executable file.

Comment: @Luke Asch: Another interessing document would be the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/latest/)

Comment: @Luke Asch: I just noticed I had a typo in one of my previous comment: the part ID is `0xC07`, and not `0xCA7`, as described in the `Cortex-A7` documentation: `0xC07 Cortex-A7 MPCore part number.`

Comment: @Frant Thanks for the clarification. That ARM architecture reference manual looks to be quite heavy, but it does help demystify the correct compilation parameters that you suggested. I will check the version of libc and report back soon - hopefully it's not too old to lack certain function calls that are necessary.

Comment: @Luke Asch: You don't need it for now, this is just that this is always interesting to know what important documentation is relevant to your SoC. Regarding libc, I was more thinking about verifying your system is using [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), or [uclibc](https://uclibc-ng.org/), or [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/) , since this would determine  your choice of a toolchain.  Hopefully it will use `glibc`.

Comment: @Frant Of course, I totally appreciate the documentation even if it's a little above my skill level. I wasn't able to find any references to a version number from an executable using `readelf -d`, but using `objdump -T` I see references to `GLIBC_2.4`. I may simply not understand the original command's output, so here is a pastebin with relevant output: https://pastebin.com/UuJeK6fm Hopefully this means that the toolchain you mentioned is acceptable to use for this modem? When researching, I read that certain instructions may be slightly different between "none" and "oe", but I will try anyway

Comment: Update: I tried the command `./arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread hello.c -o hello -lcrypt -mtune=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4  -mfloat-abi=hard`, however on the target device I still get "cannot execute binary file". Would it help for me to upload a sample executable from the modem to inspect?
(the extra parameters I have added are needed for the security vulnerability program to compile correctly)

Comment: @Luke Asch Yes, having an executable retrieved form the modem and run `readelf -h ` on on this executable and on the one you compiled  would help. Can you execute `uname -a` on the modem as well ? Please augment your question with the outputs in text format, images are really  a pain - thanks.

Comment: I need to check, but glibc 2.4 was released in 2006, and I am not sure a recent toolchain will work. Please add the output for command `cat /proc/version`  and `uname -a` first, you need yo know the kernel version.

Comment: The exact model of your modem may help as well.

Comment: Sure thing, let me gather up some information on all that.

Comment: @Frant The model name is coolpad cp331a, it was listed as a t-mobile branded modem but it might have other carrier variants. Here's a pastebin with all relevant info: https://pastebin.com/bSJmvq2E Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: @Luke Asch: it seems that even though your SoC does support hardware floating-point, your system was built using `arm-linux-gnueabi`, and not `arm-linux-gnueabihf`: see `0x5000000, Version5 EABI` versus `0x5000400, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI`.I would therefore suggest to try next with a [Linaro 4.9.4 arm-linux-gnueabi toolchain](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-4/arm-linux-gnueabi/) , not a recent `arm-linux-gnueabihf`, and to remove options  `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4  -mfloat-abi=hard`. Your system was built with `gcc version 4.9.3`

Comment: @Luke Asch: Also, I we were ultimately able to reach your goal, would you consider accepting an answer I would build from out exchanges ? in the case you would consider those exchanges helped, of course.

Comment: @Frant of course I would be okay with that, thank you very much for the help thus far. I did think it was strange that the executables from the modem were not compiled for hard-float ABI, and your answer just confirmed my suspicions. I will get back to you soon with my results.

Comment: It worked well, thank you!

Comment: @Luke Asch:  Any updates ? thanks.

Comment: @Frant sorry for not being more precise, I tried your suggestion yesterday and I was able to compile C code for this device using the toolchain you specified and the -mtune=cortex-a7 flag. Thank you very much for your help! (Sadly the code I was testing did not work. I was trying to exploit the dirtycow vulnerability using various proof-of-concept programs, but they all seemed to hang. Perhaps this is due to the device running Quallcom LE software instead of pure linux, or simply the architecture?)